# Best way to display a key-value list with material design?

Tags: website-design, lists, guidelines, material-design, design-frameworks

For a "Material design" project, I need to display a key-value list with multiple items, something like that (example with an animal and 4 criteria):

- Name: Cat
- Category: Mammal
- Color: Black
- Size: Small

I would like to see a clear distinction between the key and the value.

But I can't find anything in the specification that offers an idea for the key-value lists: https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html

There are only lists that only display a sequence of values, or lists with a first black text followed by a second gray text (which specifies the previous text).

Do you have a good idea to post a clear and beautiful key-value list with Material Design please?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a [data table](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#) of two columns, or are you looking to display a different list (in 
a different container) for each animal?

Comment: In addition to Alvaro; maybe a list of cards where every animal is one card.

Comment: @Alvaro If there is only the above four details, then which is the best way

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted a strict key value list, the [data table guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#) are the most fitting. To bring out one column over the other, feel free to bold it or make it a disctintly lighter gray (not light gray, though—it still needs to be readable).

However, for most situations, carefully considering how to present each element works best.

Some ideas:

[image: Contact page]

1. See how the name and address "John Doe", "Seattle, WA", don't require a label. Instead, the meaning and significance is obvious from the content, the layout, and the typography. Consider whether some of your key-value pairs could be translated into **just values** with the right typography and layout.
2. See how the phone area, the email area, and the location area all use icons as a label. If your keys are easy to translate into **icons**, this might be a solution.
3. Notice how the phone number and the email have a label below in a lighter gray. Consider a **two-row layout** like this, where the other row displays the category in a smaller, lighter text.

Answer (score 1):

I think about 2 options: cards or chips. Just with chips, i would do left part colorful which would represent some category of keys and right side white background black text of value. If you only have 4 categories i would probably choose chips with left background with your primary color and right white background with black text.

E.g.: Instead of "C" enter "Color:" or another category

[image]

https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html
https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `table` within a `mat-card-content`. Two cells in each row, one for key and the other one for the value plus some styling.